# C For loop output error (control may reach end of non-void function)

Tags: c, cs50

I have the following code in Python and I want to translate it in C:

```
n=input('input a number between 1 and 8')
for i in range(0,n):
    print (i*'#')
```

My for loop does nothing. Why? So far I have:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int get_positive_int(string prompt);
char func(int n);

int main(void)
{
    int i = get_positive_int("Positive integer between 1 and 8: ");
    printf("%i\n", i);
}

int get_positive_int(string prompt)
{
    int n;
    do
    {
        n = get_int("%s", prompt);
    }    
    while (n>8 || n<1);
    printf("Stored: ");
    return n;   
}


char func(int n)
{
    for (int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        for (int k=0;k<n;k++) 
        {    
            return printf("#");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't call `func`.

Comment: Did you forget to call `func`?

Comment: Also your inner loop should go up to `j` not `n`.

Comment: `printf("%i\n", i);` should be `printf("%d\n", i);`

Comment: Is `get_int` provided for you? That's not a standard function. If not, `scanf` would be useful

Comment: This code is probably a good deal more complicated than it has to be.  You can get your n with printf and scanf.  func looks OK, but why are you returning on a printf there?

Comment: The inner loop of `func` unconditionally returns from the function, so it's not much of a loop.

Comment: @ikegami `i` and `d` are synonymous as conversion specifier. There is a cs50.h which probably provides get_int.

Comment: @AProgrammer, I did not know that. But my comment stands... `%d` is almost universally used, so `%d` is far more readable than `%i`. /// It might. It might not. That's why I asked.

Comment: Also there is a separate stack exchange for cs50 - https://cs50.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never called `func`, so of course it does nothing. The error in your question title "control may reach end of non-void function)" is because you declared `func` to return `char`, but the implementation won't `return` anything if `n` is less than or equal to 0 (the loop ends immediately).

The `return` you have there doesn't make sense in any event, since the return value from `printf` isn't really relevant here. And it's printing the same number of pound signs (`#`) on each line, not an increasing number. I suspect you want something like (changes noted with inline comments):

```
void func(int n) // return type void so no return needed
{
    for (int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        for (int k=0;k<j;k++)  // k < j, not k < n, so #s increase from 0 to n
        {    
            printf("#");  // no return so loop runs to completion
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. **You don't call `func`.** I think this is easily understandable.
2. **Why are you declaring `func()` with `char` return type?** It should not return anything.
3. **Don't `return` anything.** Don't `return` the `printf`. Why would you want to do that? You only want to print the characters. `return` immediately exits the function.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should **include** string.h and stdlib.h
2. You are using invalid data type for string. You should use **(const char *prompt[])**
3. **while(n > 8 || n < 1)** is telling the loop to store numbers outside of the specified range, not inside. It should be **while(n <= 8 && n >= 1)** if you want it to be inclusive otherwise you can omit the **=** operator.
4. The python code does not really work either. What is the purpose of this for loop? What is the desired output?

Comment: Indeed at 4. i forgot an int in  'range(0,int(n))' because the input gives a string not an int.  The code should do a very basic pyramid